# Permissions-error using bash-script to install a library in R

Tags: r, bash, permissions, file-permissions

I am running a software called CNV-Seq in a Bash script but, I do not have permission to run the following command:

`R CMD INSTALL cnv/`

The error is

```
* installing to library '/share/apps/r/3.2.2/intel/lib64/R/library'
Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory '/share/apps/r/3.2.2/intel/lib64/R/library'
```

How can I solve this problem without gaining permission.

Comment: You can install to home based directories that you have access to. How to do this depends on whether you are compiling from source, or the package manager you are using. You can also check sudoers and see if any commands run as root - you never know there may be a backdoor. Some commercial software installations for example have tar in sudoers, which allows unlimited root access to the system.

Comment: What is the output of `.libPaths()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is creating the bash script that executes R script.
So, the R script will contain:

```
install.packages("package_name")
```

Save it as `xyz.r`

and the bash script will contain:

```
R -f path_to/xyz.r
```

Save that as `abc`.

Run the bash script like this:

```
bash abc
```

Comment: Please use the comments for such question.

Comment: I would have commented if and only if I had 50 reps. I cant comment on questions and answers by other people. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It will probably fail if you don't specify a local folder. As it, it will certainly try to install package in `'/share/apps/r/3.2.2/intel/lib64/R/library'`.